# If main() finishes before the threads it has created, and exits will other threads continue to execute created by main?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

If main() finishes before the threads it has created, and exits with pthread_exit(), will other threads continue to execute created by main()?

Comment: What have your experiments told you?

Comment: I presume you're considering threads created with `pthread_create`? You do know that C++ has `std::thread`? The C++ Standard does not describe how pthreads work, only how `std::thread` works.